# Lists and lambda expression

Tags: python

First of all, hello, I have a little question. I'm trying to learn how to use lambda expression etc... I have this bit of code, it's an example that I need to replicate.

```
>>>something (lambda x:x+1, lambda y:y+10, [1, 2, 3, 4])
[2, 12, 4, 14]
```

I need that output and so far I got this:

```
l = [1,2,3,4]
def result(l):
    o = l[0::2]
    o2 = l[1::2]
    p = map(lambda x:x+1,o)
    p2 = map(lambda y:y+10,o2)
    return p,p2
```

First of all I know I'm returning 2 separated lists, I'm trying to figure that one out.

Is there any way to do this without having p and p2 separated?
Something like this:

```
p = map(lambda x,y: x+1 x+10, o,o2)
```

*I know that line doesn't work I'm just trying to illustrate what I'm asking*

Comment: What is `something`?

Comment: random name couldn't come up with a better one.

Answer (score 1):

You're using those `lambda` functions wrongly. Why use multiple lambda functions to process a simple list? You can use just one, with a list comprehension:

```
r = [1, 2, 3, 4]
func = lambda x: [v+1 if i%2==0 else v+10 for i,v in enumerate(x)]
func(r)
# [2, 12, 4, 14]
```

You may even prefer writing a *proper* function for this for readability.

Or better, you can even do without the lambda function altogether:

```
[v+1 if i%2 == 0 else v+10 for i,v in enumerate(x)]
```

Comment: Simpler: `[value + (1 if i % 2 == 0 else 10) for i, value in enumerate(lst)]`

Comment: With a list comprehension, there is no need for a lambda function.

Comment: @azalea OP apparently wants to understand more about lambda functions

Comment: Sounds like they should understand first that one's not needed here :D

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each of the lambda expressions are used on every second value of the third argument to `something` you could simply overwrite the list(or alternatively make a new one):

```
def something(f1,f2,lst):
    for i,li in enumerate(lst):
        if not i%2: 
            lst[i] = f1(li)
        else:  
            lst[i] = f2(li)
    return lst

something (lambda x:x+1, lambda y:y+10, [1, 2, 3, 4])
#[2, 12, 4, 14]
```

This is by no means optimized, but it is readable.

Comment: Well... that is something

Answer (score 0):

The other answers will work, but if your question is just one case were you need to cycle several functions to be applied to different elements of a list, and then repeat the functions - then, semantically, a combination of `zip` and `itertools.cycle` would be a nice approach:

```
from itertools import cycle
[f(n) for f, n in zip(cycle((lambda x: x + 1, lambda x: x + 10)), [1, 2, 3, 4])]
```

Output:

```
[2, 12, 4, 14]
```